# Troubleshooting AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the http://www.ted.com/talks page for all the names of the talk. Using BeautifulSoup, here is what I have:

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ted.com/talks")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

link = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.findParent('dt', 'thumbnail'))

for anchor in link.findAll('a', title = True):
    print anchor['title']
```

The initial "link" displays a nice array of the block of eight videos there. I then try to go through this and take out the titles in the  tags, using the above code, which gives me the following error:

```
for anchor in link.findAll('a', title=True):
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link` is a collection of `Tag` objects, which you need to iterate over. For example:

```
for anchor in link:
    print anchor['title']
```

Comment: This gives the following error:     print a['title']
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: @Adam sorry, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Looks fascinating. Thanks! Know of where I could learn more about 'anchor' syntax? Example: Say I wanted the <img> and not the <a> tags. Would I just change the findAll('img' ?? Just curious to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

By way of comparison, a pyparsing approach would look like this:

```
from contextlib import closing
import urllib2
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute

# pull HTML from web page
with closing(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ted.com/talks")) as page:
    html = page.read()

# define opening and closing tags
dt,dtEnd = makeHTMLTags("dt")
a,aEnd = makeHTMLTags("a")

# restrict <dt> tag matches to those with class='thumbnail'
dt.setParseAction(withAttribute(**{'class':'thumbnail'}))

# define pattern of <dt> tag followed immediately by <a> tag
patt =  dt + a("A")

# scan input html for matches of this pattern, and access
# attributes of the <A> tag
for match,s,e in patt.scanString(html):
    print match.A.title
    print match.A.href
    print
```

Giving:

```
Bruce Schneier: The security mirage
/talks/bruce_schneier.html

Harvey Fineberg: Are we ready for neo-evolution?
/talks/harvey_fineberg_are_we_ready_for_neo_evolution.html

Ric Elias: 3 things I learned while my plane crashed
/talks/ric_elias.html

Anil Ananthaswamy: What it takes to do extreme astrophysics
/talks/anil_ananthaswamy.html

John Hunter on the World Peace Game
/talks/john_hunter_on_the_world_peace_game.html

Kathryn Schulz: On being wrong
/talks/kathryn_schulz_on_being_wrong.html

Sam Richards: A radical experiment in empathy
/talks/sam_richards_a_radical_experiment_in_empathy.html

Susan Lim: Transplant cells, not organs
/talks/susan_lim.html

Marcin Jakubowski: Open-sourced blueprints for civilization
/talks/marcin_jakubowski.html

Roger Ebert: Remaking my voice
/talks/roger_ebert_remaking_my_voice.html
```

Comment: Thanks for that extra perspective :)